# How to get information about linked files?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

I have a scene with several objects and groups linked from other files.

How to know what file contains my linked object or group?

Comment: Have you tried the outliner in *Blend Files* mode?

Comment: Yes, but I still can not find the information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 ways to get the information I need.

1. Using **Edit Linked Library plugin** (Object : Edit Linked Library) is rather helpful.

[image: Edit Linked Library plugin[1]]

It allows me not only to see what file contains the selected linked object but to switch to its editing from the Relations tab of the Tool Shelf.

---

2. Other way is to use the **Blender File** mode of the **Outliner**. It shows the sources of all connected data (objects, materials, armatures etc...), but does not highlight links of the selected object (at least I did not find the way to do it).

One can use search by name of the object to find all information needed.

[image: Blender file in the Outliner]